# what was it...what it was

Tags: word-order, syntax

I live in the Middle East and have acquired my English skills orally and from experience rather than academically, and there's a certain structure that English-speaking people in my vicinity use often.

In a sentence like:

> 'John was troubled by something but I didn't know what it was/what was it.'

From experience, I feel that 'what it was' is correct but I don't know why and most nonnative speakers would use the other construction. Can somebody explain or at least tell me what topic in a grammar book would deal with this kind of structure so I could read about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct form would be

> John was troubled by something but I didn't know what it was.

English usually forms sentences with a subject-verb-object structure, as in your first clause:

> **John** *(subject)* was **troubled** *(verb)* by **something** *(object)*

The second clause is a little more complex:

> **I** *(subject)* didn't **know** *(verb)* what **it** *(object)* was.

"what it was" here is an [***adjunct clause***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause#Adjunct_clauses) with "what" as a subordinate conjunction, which modifies the matrix clause "I didn't know".

Note that if you were to turn this into a question, you would use [***subject-auxiliary inversion***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion):

> What was it?

(Disclaimer: there are a number of grammatical topics covered here and it's almost certain that I've made a mistake somewhere along the line, so please feel free to edit the answer or comment pointing out anything I haven't explained properly).